# Read frame as bitmap object from vlc.net

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I'm using `vlc.net` for playing RTSP with below code:

```
vlcControl1.VlcMediaPlayer.Play("rtsp://192.168.1.100/profile1/media.smp");
```

Now i want to get video frame by frame. I create a threat and take a snapshot inside it and then read file to bitmap file:

```
while (true)
{
    string frameFilePath=Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/frames/", "cur.bmp");
    vlcControl.TakeSnapshot(frameFilePath);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

But this way is very slow because of I/O. does any fast solution exists for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, and the WPF integration for Vlc.DotNet does it.

See full code here https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/blob/develop/src/Vlc.DotNet.Wpf/VlcVideoSourceProvider.cs